# How to extract the polynomial and the non-polynomial parts from a sympy equation?

Tags: python, math, sympy, polynomials

```
from sympy import Symbol

x = Symbol('x')
equation = x**2 + 2**x - 2*x - 5**x + 1
```

Here, in this equation, for example, the polynomial part is `x**2 - 2*x + 1` while the non-polynomial part is `2**x - 5**x`.

Given an equation, how to extract the polynomial and the non-polynomial parts of it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `as_poly` method to find the terms that are polynomial in the given symbol:

```
In [1]: from sympy import Symbol
   ...: 
   ...: x = Symbol('x')
   ...: equation = x**2 + 2**x - 2*x - 5**x + 1

In [2]: poly, nonpoly = [], []

In [3]: for term in Add.make_args(equation):
   ...:     if term.as_poly(x) is not None:
   ...:         poly.append(term)
   ...:     else:
   ...:         nonpoly.append(term)
   ...: 

In [4]: poly
Out[4]: 
⎡    2      ⎤
⎣1, x , -2⋅x⎦

In [5]: nonpoly
Out[5]: 
⎡ x    x⎤
⎣2 , -5 ⎦

In [6]: Add(*poly)
Out[6]: 
 2          
x  - 2⋅x + 1

In [7]: Add(*nonpoly)
Out[7]: 
 x    x
2  - 5
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.expr.Expr.as_poly

Answer (score 0):

Separate all the terms first,

```
lst = equation.args
```

Use the `degree()` function in sympy module to find the degree of each term in `lst`. It gives a `PolynomialError`, if a term is not a polynomial.

Error can be handled using `try ... except` statements.